# Customize Chromium with user.css like in Firefox

Tags: firefox, chromium, customization

in firefox I edit userChrome.css file for customize the bookmarks bar with this code:

File in `/home/gabriel/.mozilla/firefox/t5w3u0oy.default/chrome/userChrome.css`

Code:

```
 /* kill icons for bookmark folders in Bookmarks menu */
.bookmark-item[type="menu"] > .toolbarbutton-icon {
  display: none;
}
/* hide text of bookmarks*/
.bookmark-item:not(.bookmark-group):not([type="menu"]) > .toolbarbutton-text {
display:none !important;
}
```

My **question** is **how to do the same in chromium,** the Custom.css file I found in this folder:

```
/home/gabriel/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think for chromium (not sure about chrome) you can edit that `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`

At least I have and found it works.

For blocking the sponsored ads on startpage.com for example, edit/create the file and add:

```
div#sponsored {display:none; }
```

Save it.

Run a search on startpage and see if the sponsored ads are displayed at the top.

Seems to work for me anyway.

Comment: doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, Chromium (and Chrome) do not allow customization of browser components (or "chrome") by means of CSS. In other words, Chromium (and Chrome) do not have the equivalent of **userChrome.css**. The **Custom.css** you refer to is similar in function to **userContent.css** in Firefox, by means of which you can alter the appearance of web pages.

You may already know that a very restricted extent of changing only the appearance of "chrome" items can be achieved by changing themes (accessible near the bottom of the page accessed via **Wrench, Preferences, Personal Stuff** or by typing <kbd>chrome://settings/personal</kbd> in the url bar and hitting enter).

Comment: The only customizacion that I could do is change the color and size of thr scrollbar with: `::-webkit-scrollbar {} `editing the file: `/home/gabriel/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`

Comment: I hope I can customize the bookmark bar too.

Comment: From what I recall, tweaking the scrollbars leads to loss of the indicators that show up in the vertical scrollbar when one uses the "find" function on pages that are more than one screen long. Anyway, all the best.